# More efficient RewriteRule for messy URL

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have developed a new web site to replace an existing one for a client. Their previous site had some pretty nasty looking URLs to their products. For example, an old URL:

`http://mydomain.com/p/-3-0-Some-Ugly-Product-Info-With-1-3pt-/a-arbitrary-folder/-18pt/-1-8pt-/ABC1234`

I want to catch all requests to the new site that use these old URLs. The information I need out of the old URL is the `ABC1234` which is the product ID. To clarify, the old URL begins with `/p/` followed by four levels of folders, then the product ID.

So for example, the above URL needs to get rewritten to this:

`http://mydomain.com/shop/?sku=ABC1234`

I'm using Apache 2.2 on Linux. Can anyone point me on the correct pattern to match? I know this is wrong, but here is where I am currently at:

`RewriteRule ^p/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$   shop/?sku=$5 [R=301,NC,L]`

I'm pretty sure that the pattern used to match each of the 4 folders is redundant, but I'm just not that sharp with regex. I've tried some online regex evaluators with no success.

Thank you.

**--EDIT #1--**

Actually, my RewriteRule above does work, but is there a way to shorten it up?

**--EDIT #2--**

Thanks to ddr, I've been able to get this expression down to this:

`RewriteRule ^p/([\w-]+/){4}([\w-]+)$   shop/?_sku=$2 [R=301,NC,L]`

**--EDIT #3--**

Mostly for the benefit of ddr, but I welcome anyone to assist who can. I'm dealing with over 10,000 URLs that need to be rewritten to work with a new site. The information I've provided so far still stands, but now that I am testing that all of the old URLs are being rewritten properly I am running into a few anomolies that don't work with the RewriteRule example provided by ddr.

The old URLs are consistent in that the product ID I need is at the very end of the URL as documented above. The first folder is always `/p/`. The problem I am running into at this point is that some of the URLs have a URL encoded double quote ("). Additionally, some of the URLs contain a /-/ as one of the four folders mentioned. So here are some examples of the variations in the old URLs:

```
/p/-letters-numbers-hyphens-88/another-folder/-and-another-/another-18/ABC1234

/p/-letters-numbers-hyphens-88/2%22/-/-/ABCD1234

/p/letters-numbers-hyphens-1234/34-88/-22/-/ABCD1234/
```

Though the old URLs are nasty, I think it is safe to say that the following are always true:

- Each begins with /p/
- Each ends with the product ID that I need to isolate.
- There are always four levels of folders between /p/ and the product ID.
- Some folders in between have hyphens, some don't.
- Some folders in between are a hyphen ONLY.
- Some folders in between contain a % character where they are URL encoded.
- Some requests include a `/` at the very end and some do not.

The following rule was provided by ddr and worked great until I ran into the URLs that contain a % percent sign or a folder with only a hyphen:

`RewriteRule ^p/(?:[\w-]+/){4}([\w-]+)$ shop/?_sku=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Given the rule above, how do I edit it to allow for a folder that is hyphen only (/-/) or for a percent sign?

Comment: I don't think it makes a difference, but the first 4 capture groups seem unnecessary.

Comment: I'm sure they are at least redundant, but it doesn't work anyway. It doesn't seem to be matching the old URL at all. :S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use character classes to reduce some of the length. The parentheses (capture groups) are also unnecessary, except the last one, as @jpmc26 says.

I'm not especially familiar with Apache rules, but try this:

`RewriteRule ^p/(?:[\w-]+/){4}([\w-]+)$ shop/?sku=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

It should work if extended regular expressions are supported.

- `\w` is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]` and you don't need to *not* capture underscores, so that's one replacement.
- The `{4}` matches exactly four repetitions of the previous group. This is not always supported so Apache may not like it.
- The `?:` is optional but indicates that these parens should not be treated as a capture. Makes it slightly more efficient.

I'm not sure what the part in [] at the end is for but I left it. I can't see why you'd need a `?` before the `$`, so I took it out.

Edit: the most compact way, if Apache likes it, would probably be

`RewriteRule ^p(/[\w-]+){5}$ shop/?sku=$5 [R=301,NC,L]`

EDIT: response to edit 3 of the question.

I'm surprised it doesn't work with only `-`. The `[\w-]+` should match even where there is just a single `-`. Are you sure there isn't something else going on in these URLs?

You might also try replacing `-` in the regex with `\-`.

As for the `%`, just change `[\w-]` to `[\w%-]`. Make sure you leave the `-` at the end! Otherwise the regex engine will try to interpret it as part of a char sequence.

EDIT 2: Or try this:
`RewriteRule ^p/(?:.*?/){4}(.*?)/?$ shop/?sku=$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: Neither of your examples worked as-is, but you sure got me a lot closer! This works: `^p/([\w-]+/){4}([\w-]+)$  shop/?_sku=$2` - maybe this is closer as to where you/someone can make it even shorter for me, but to be honest it isn't so bad the way it is. Thank you very much.

Comment: ddr - this works too: ^p/(?:[\w-]+/){4}([\w-]+)$  shop/?_sku=$1 - had to remove the `/` after `{4}`.

Comment: oh man, missed the extra slash. Glad it works! What happened with my second regex?

Comment: I got a 404 Not Found with the second one and it's so short I didn't see anything I could change. Would be nice to make the pattern rule shorter, but it's reduced considerably. :)

Comment: @rwkiii I think the problem with the second pattern was the slash at the end. I changed it--try it now?

Comment: ddr, It still didn't work. The rewritten url becomes `/shop/?sku=`. I changed the sku=$5, to sku=$4, then $3, $2 and the results were all the same. When I changed it to $1 the result was different. Changing the rule to `^p(/[\w-]+){5}$ shop/?sku=$1` results in `shop/?sku=/ABC1234` which is very close, but contains the unwanted `/` just before the product ID.

Comment: ddr, see my not above, but additionally I just found some instances where the old URLs contain a `%` percent sign. They all appear to be %22 which is a URL encoded `"` double quote. I think the rule doesn't account for these and so when a percent sign appears in the old URL the rewrite rule breaks. These percent signs are completely unimportant for my purpose, but need to be accounted for. I'm going to see if I can figure out how to allow for them in the rule you provided me. If I succeed I will edit my post and comment it here. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: ddr (or anyone else), please see Edit #3 in my initial post above.